# Factor Analysis with Mixed Data Concurrent Approach with PCAmixdata in R

Tags: r, pca, dimensionality-reduction, exploratory-factor-analysis

I am trying to perform Factor Analysis over Mixed Data using R with PCAmixdata package. My dataset is huge with almost 115000 records and almost 40 features of both categorical and continuous. When I tried to run PCAmixdata, I am getting memory issue that total memory allocation is reached and I am not able to proceed, I wanted to know if it is a right way to split the dataset row-wise like 30000 records at a time and combine the results of PCAmixdata. If not I want to know what are the other possible ways to overcome this issue.